# The right order of values for Bollinger Bands

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use the Bollinger Bands demo from the official Highcharts docs [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wuorc62k/):

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-ohlc.json', function (data) {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'ohlc',
            id: 'aapl',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data
        }, {
            type: 'bb',
            linkedTo: 'aapl'
        }]
    });
});
```

And when I visit the JSON link provided (https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-ohlc.json), I see data in the following format:

```
[
  [
    1467984600000,
    96.49,
    96.89,
    96.05,
    96.68,
  ],
  [
    1468243800000,
    96.75,
    97.65,
    96.73,
    96.98,
  ],   
  ...
]
```

What I'm confused about is what these values represent, in order. The first one is surely the timestamp;the second one should be the running average ... then what are the next three, in order? Please note that I understand the idea behind Bollinger Bands and have done the required calculations, but I think I'm not getting a band because I'm unsure about the order.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the OHLC series is [defined in the API](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.ohlc.data), but essentially the format you see is as follows:

> An array of arrays with 5 or 4 values. In this case, the values correspond to `x,open,high,low,close`.

Or you could do it with objects:

```
{
    x: 1,
    open: 3,
    high: 4,
    low: 5,
    close: 2,
    name: "Point name"
}
```

When you then include `indicators.js` followed by `bollinger-bands.js` you should get your Bollinger bands calculated and shown by linking the `bb`series to the `ohlc` series without actually providing any additional data for the Bollinger bands themselves.

Some additional `plotOptions` exist for the Bollinger Bands, as [seen in the API](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.bb).

Comment: Talk about epiphany! I was doing all the calculations manually and passing them.

Comment: @dotslash Never hurts to know the calculations though! I guess you could make them as simple line series supporting the OHLC series, but automatically seems nice as well :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I did try searching the API but was unsure what I had to be looking for.